Printing nested HTML tables in PyQt6
I have an issue when trying to print the contents of a QTableWidget in a PyQt6 application.
It actually works, but there is a small problem: I have tables embedded in the main table and I'd like those tables to completely fill the parent cells (100% of their widths), but the child tables don't expand as expected.
This is my code:
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt6.QtGui import QTextDocument


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Print TableWidget')
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_table)

    def print_table(self):
        html_table = '''
            <table cellpadding="0">
                <tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data1</td>
                    <td>data2</td>
                    <td><table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>data3</td><td>data3</td><td>data3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data1</td>
                    <td>data2</td>
                    <td><table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>hr1</th><th>hr2</th><th>hr3</th><th>hr4</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>d3</td><td>d3</td><td>d3</td><td>d3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>d3</td><td>d3</td><td>d3</td><td>d3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        '''

        style_sheet = '''
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse; 
                width: 100%;
            }
            th {
                background-color: lightblue; 
                border: 1px solid gray; 
                height: 1em;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px solid gray; 
                padding: 0; 
                vertical-align: top;
            }
        '''
        text_doc = QTextDocument()
        text_doc.setDefaultStyleSheet(style_sheet)
        text_doc.setHtml(html_table)
        prev_dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        prev_dialog.paintRequested.connect(text_doc.print)
        prev_dialog.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(640,480)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

And this is what i get:

But this is what i want:

I would appreciate any suggestions about this problem, as I have no idea about how to fix it.

What does your QTableWidget look like? Does it have embedded QTableWidgets? Does it have a fixed structure? How do you plan to generate the HTML from the widgets?

@ekhumoro, yes my 'QTableWidget' has embedded QTableWidgets, its structure isn't fixed (columns and rows number in child widget can be different), and i generate the HTML dynamicly

@ekhumoro, My data source is actually a pandas DataFrame, I display it in the QTableWidget and then use this dataframe to generate HTML table.

In that case, you can use QWebEnginePage to render the HTML/CSS, which will give you many more formatting options than QTextDocument. For a complete demo showing how to print/preview the rendered page, see this answer. It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the code to your use-case. (PS: to set a default stylesheet, you can use script injection)

@ekhumoro, Thank you so much, this is a really great idea, I will definitely try this widget.

The rich text in Qt only provides a limited subset of HTML and CSS. More specifically, it only provides what QTextDocument allows, and the HTML parsing is therefore completely based on the QTextDocument capabilities.
Complex layouts that may be easier to achieve with standard HTML and CSS in a common web browser, may be difficult if not impossible to get in Qt, and the documentation has to be carefully checked.
Specifically, the width property is not listed in the CSS Properties list.
Nonetheless, it is supported as an HTML attribute for many tags, including table and their cells.
Note: there may be occurrences of tags/CSS behavior that works "as expected" even if not documented, but you shall not rely on those, unless it's been found consistent in multiple and previous Qt versions, and possibly upon careful checking of consistency in the sources, both for the parser, and the document layout structure.
Just remove that property from the CSS, and use it as an attribute, for example:
<table width="100%">
    ...
    <tr><td width="75%">
        <table width="100%">
            ...
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>

The above will make the parent table occupy the full viewport (or page) width, with the column containing the nested table being 75% of that width, and that table occupying the cell in full, horizontally.
UPDATE
As properly noted by ekhumoro's comment, though, there is a bug that actually prevents setting any numerical value of width, with the result that, no matter what, the table will always occupy almost the full width of the cell.
In case you want the nested table to occupy just a percentage of the "parent cell", the work around for that is by setting percentages for each of its columns.
Consider the following header syntax for the second nested table:
<tr>
    <th width=20%>hr1</th>
    <th width=20%>hr2</th>
    <th width=20%>hr3</th>
    <th width=20%>hr4</th>
</tr>

Which, along with the first snippet above, will result in a table that properly occupies 80% of the cell width:

You'll probably notice a small margin on the left and top of the tables, which is probably caused by the border-collapse property, and another demonstration of the limitations of Qt's rich text engine, which was not intended for pixel-perfect rendering and initially implemented in a more "flexible" (not design-oriented) intention of hyper text display.
A possible work around may be to completely avoid border collapse, and use the table attribute cellspacing=0 instead; it may not be always appropriate, but it works in your specific case, and can be eventually fixed with a more carefully written CSS based on class selectors.
For instance by setting a class for the table and explicitly declaring the rules for cells (eg: table.nested td { ... }).
As already noted, if you want more control on the layout/appearance and more compliant support for modern HTML and CSS standards, the only option is to use the QtWebEngine related classes. Be aware, though, that that module alone is more than 150MB in size, so consider that requirement carefully.

This doesn't really work - i.e. it won't exactly match what the OP says they want. The OP may choose to accept it anyway, since it appears to be "close enough". But setting the width attribute will only make the embedded tables fill most of the space (and not completely accurately either, since there's some clipping). To see how cranky the implementation is, note that setting the width of the embedded tables to 0%, 42%, etc rather than 100% makes no difference.

@ekhumoro You're perfectly right, my bad: I didn't test it thoroughly enough. Yet, I found out that setting percentages for the cells, instead, works as expected (see the update in the answer), even though I'm not sure about why; my guess is that it depends on the order in which the parser constructs objects (when the QTextTableFormat and its column width constraints are eventually set). About the "most" space, I suppose you're referring to the top-left margins, but I'm not completely sure it's actually clipping: I believe it's a slight translation caused by the (inherited?) border-collapse.

@musicamante, Thank you for such a detailed answer, it helped me a lot.

@SergFSM If you're still interested, I have now added an answer with an improved solution using QTextDocument that removes all the small gaps and doubled borders.

A complete solution is possible with QTextDocument, but it requires very careful handling to work around some issues with the limited subset of HTML/CSS currently supported by Qt. The main issue is the buggy implementation of the border-collapse CSS property, which leaves ugly gaps around the table margins. It's therefore best to avoid using this property and implement custom handling of the borders instead. Here is what I managed to achieve by using this approach:

As you can see, there are no gaps or doubled borders.
To achieve this, it's necessary to set some HTML attributes which aren't available via CSS. All the tables must have cellspacing="0", and the embedded tables must have width="100%". The main columns must be adjusted by setting the width attributes on the tr tags of the outer table. However, you should note that there's a small bug which may cause some borders to be clipped, depending on the exact percentage values used. (I found that it helps to have the values sum to 99%, but some experimentation may be needed to achieve perfect results).
The borders need to be set explicitly using CSS. This must be done using the adjacent-sibling selector (+), as Qt does not support pseudo-classes like :first-child. Finally, the outer table must be embedded in a div to allow child selectors (>) to be used.
Here is a complete demo based on the original example:
    import sys
    from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
    from PyQt6.QtGui import QTextDocument
    
    
    class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
            self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Print TableWidget')
            self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_table)
    
        def print_table(self):
            html_table = '''
                <div>
                <table cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="18%">header1</th>
                        <th width="18%">header2</th>
                        <th width="63%">header3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>data1</td>
                        <td>data2</td>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>header1</th>
                                    <th>header2</th>
                                    <th>header3</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>data3</td>
                                    <td>data3</td>
                                    <td>data3</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>data1</td>
                        <td>data2</td>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>hr1</th>
                                    <th>hr2</th>
                                    <th>hr3</th>
                                    <th>hr4</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                    <td>d3</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            '''
    
            style_sheet = '''
                th {
                    background-color: lightblue;
                    height: 1em;
                    }
                td {
                    padding: 0;
                    vertical-align: top;
                    text-align: center;
                    }
                div > table th {
                    border: 1px solid gray;
                    }
                div > table td {
                    border: 1px solid gray;
                    border-top: 0px;
                    }
                div > table td + td {
                    border-left: 0px;
                    }
                div > table th + th {
                    border-left: 0px;
                    }
                table table th + th {
                    border-left: 1px solid gray;
                    }
                table table td {
                    border-top: 1px solid gray;
                    }
                table table td + td {
                    border-left: 1px solid gray;
                    }
            '''
            text_doc = QTextDocument()
            text_doc.setDefaultStyleSheet(style_sheet)
            text_doc.setHtml(html_table)
            prev_dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
            prev_dialog.paintRequested.connect(text_doc.print)
            prev_dialog.exec()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        widget = MyWidget()
        widget.resize(640, 480)
        widget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())


Uhm, text-align: center; is supported by td. I tested your code removing all align="center" and just adding that property to the basic td selector works the same.

@musicamante Okay, thanks, I've adjusted the code accordingly. Why isn't it properly documented, though?

Good question. As I wrote in my answer, there are some undocumented aspects in the rich text engine and HTML/CSS parsing, and besides small changes (such as the introduction of cell-specific borders in 5.14) that implicitly expanded the class docs, the more descriptive documentation hasn't been updated (or fixed) in years; maybe it's worth a report. In this case, though, I'd say that we can assume it as reliable, since it's part of the original CSS implementation and is consistent with QTextBlockFormat.

@musicamante I did look at this when I was developing my solution, but I just assumed that since vertical-align is properly documented (which corresponds with the valign attribute), then text-align must not be supported. I mean, why document one property, but not the other? How many other undocumented features are there? Issues related to limited HTML/CSS support come up quite often on SO - it really undermines the advice that can be given if there are numerous hidden features that aren't properly documented.

My assumption is that it was probably added some time ago along with other changes, but they never cared to document it (and such changes are not reflected in reference docs, as they're not automatically generated). I found out that the quite old QTBUG-2730 reported about the issue, and in fact it doesn't work on Qt4. It probably was part of other changes introduced in Qt5, and they just forgot to properly update old docs that were considered still consistent.

@ekhumoro, thank you, it really looks much better, this implementation is fantastic
